# Setting the RegionEndpoint in C# using AmazonDynamoDBConfig does not work

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Can someone please help with the following situation ?

I have a console .net50 application in which I connect to a docker container dynamodb, running on `localhost:8000`. In my config file, in my .aws folder, i have the following configuration :

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

Until here everything is good.

I create a table using the C# console application and it works.
The problem is when I try to list the table in my AWS CLI it does not show up with the default profile.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

It only shows up if I modify the region in the config file to `region = us-east-1`.

The code in my app which is handling the creation of the AmazonDynamoDBClient is the following :

```
AmazonDynamoDBConfig clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig ();            
clientConfig.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;              
clientConfig.ServiceURL = "http://localhost:8000";
AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient (credentials, clientConfig);
```

Somehow the RegionEndpoint does not get used, the default one (USEast1) is used instead.
Someone has a clue how to fix this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The properties 'clientConfig.RegionEndpoint' and 'clientConfig.ServiceURL' are mutually exclusive. So they can't be change at same time. If you're trying to hit a local DynamoDB, just change the ServiceURL and it should work fine.